# Linq to Sql - Create DB and How to query from it?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I create a table using Linq

```
PODataContext db = new PODataContext();

String query = "create table myTable(text varchar(20) primary key)";

db.ExecuteCommand(query);
```

Then I also inserted data to it.

```
String insQuery = "insert into myTable values('some text')";

db.ExecuteCommand(insQuery);
```

My problem is how do I get data from that table ?

Thank You
yohan

Comment: I don't think linq to sql is suited for using a table created in SQL. It is used by generating strongly-typed classes from an already existing database. If you want to use SQL, you might have a look at [WebMatrix.Data.Database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.data.database(VS.99).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to change (or create!) the database schema at runtime, note that LinqToSQL cannot update it's database representation at runtime as well. It can only be updated by Drag-And-Drop in Visual Studio or using SQLMetal via command line (a rather obscure method) and recompiling your application.

However, you could create a well-defined database schema with the ExecuteQuery at runtime and use the same existing database schema on your development machine to generate your LinqToSQL DataContext via drag and drop as usual.

Answer (score 1):

```
var query =from  c in new PODataContext().myTable
            select c;
```

**UPDATED**

**LINQ to SQL without using the Object Relational Designer**

Create a class named MyTable and decorate with Table attribute.

```
[Table(Name="myTable")]
public class MyTable

{
    [Column]
    public string Text 

}
```

Then create following class

```
public class PODataContext : DataContext
  {

   public Table<MyTable> myTables;

    public PODataContext(string connection): base(connection)

    {

    }

}
```

Now query your table as follows

```
var query =from  c in new PODataContext().myTable
            select c;
```

Comment: thank you for quick reply, thing is since I create table pro grammatically It is not exist in the dbml file, therefore `PODataContext().myTable` not exist

Answer (score 1):

To do a query to the database table you don't need to write string commands and call the `ExecuteQuery` method - it is only for specific database tasks that you can't do with LINQ. What you can do with LINQ is write queries like:

```
var query = from c in db.myTable
            where c.Id > 5
            select c;

foreach ( var c in query )
    Console.WriteLine( c );
```

This code take all entities from myTable that have the Id greater than 5 (`SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE Id > 5 in SQL`) and write them all to the console.

But to make it work you need to create right `DataContext` for your database. The simpliest way to do it in Visual Studio is to `Add New Item...` -> `LINQ to SQL Classes`. Then you need to connect to your database in `Server Explorer`, expand `Tables` and drag needed tables to designer window. Visual Studio automatically generates new class derived from `DataContext` that usefull for you database (for example has properties like `myTable`).

[MSDN page for `LINQ to SQL`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb386976.aspx)